# A=a+ia/b-ic +id where a,b,c,d is greater than 1 and c>b now what is the Arg(A)?

Tags: trigonometry

My attempt: =ab-ac/b²+c² +(ab+b²d+c²d+ac)i/b²+c²
Arg = arctan(ab+b²d+c²d+ac/ab-ac)
But could not find any way of range of Argument.

Comment: This Q is hard to read. Hence, consider to visit [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for format improvement.